# Call hierarchy with calls from dependencies in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, call-graph

Is it possible in Netbeans to show method calls from dependencies?

Example:
Project A depends on project B (It's gradle dependency, source is downloaded). Project A has Interface ClassX with methodX(). Project B implements it and passes it as some method argument to something in project A. It is possible to show calls of methodX() without creating separate netbeans project for project A?

Eclipse shows calls in dependencies by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue to the gradle plugin

https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project

Comment: This is probably not an issue with gradle plugin but with Netbeans. Even without the plugin, with normal Java project it looks for usages in dependencies only if the dependencies are opened in in Netbeans as other peojects. And I don't know how it could be achieved with gradle.